# Why OnMouseDown function the hit.triangleIndex return -1?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
void OnMouseDown()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            RaycastHit hit;
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 1000.0f))
            {
                int[] triangles = transform.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh.triangles;
                if (hit.triangleIndex != -1 && (hit.triangleIndex * 3) < triangles.Length)
    }
```

When i click on one of the triangles on the mesh there are two it's getting to the function using a breakpoint but i see that hit.triangleIndex is -1.

In the array triangles i have 6 items:

```
index 0 = 2
index 1 = 1 
index 2 = 0
index 3 = 2
index 4 = 3
index 5 = 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Triangle index is only valid if the collider that was hit is a
>   MeshCollider.

[RaycastHit.triangleIndex](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit-triangleIndex.html)

Comment: Right but that's the problem i had before. Until now i used BoxCollider. And i changed it now to MeshCollider: gameObject.AddComponent<MeshCollider>(); The problem now is that when i click with the mouse on the mesh it's never get into the OnMouseDown function only if i check the MeshCollider property name: Convex. If i check it set it to true it will get to the OnMouseDown. But then when running the game over again i need to set the Convex to false. Each time i need to change the Convex property to true or false else it will not get to the OnMouseDown. Any ideas why ?

Comment: @DanielHalfoni some googling reveals [this](http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/996290/view.html) gem.